# New Action to redirect to a page under Actions

Tags: action, customization, acumatica

I have browsed some questions on here already and found one that redirects to a report with some parameters. I would just like to add a new action under the Actions drop down, and it is just used to redirect to a new page in Acumatica. Specifically I am adding an action to the Cases Page (CR306000) and the button would redirect the user to the Sales Order page. I know that the code is this to create button:

```
[PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Custom Action Title")]
    protected void CustomAction()
    {
        //stuff
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
        Base.action.AddMenuAction(this.customAction);
    }
```

However, I just don't know what the code is to redirect to a new page. I'm not sure if just a URL go to is better or if there is a way to just go to a screen in a different fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact code depends on the context, whether it's in a new Graph (use 'this') or GraphExtension (use 'Base') and whether you want to select a sales order in the new page.

The most common way is to create the graph of the screen you want (in this case SalesOrderEntry) and redirect to that graph.

Here is an event handler example for a graph extension where sales order is selected for the new page:

```
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "View Sales Order")]
public virtual IEnumerable ViewSalesOrder(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    const string salesOrderNbr = "SOXXXXXXX";
    const string salesOrderType = "SO";

    SOOrderEntry salesOrderEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();

    SOOrder salesOrder = PXSelect<SOOrder,
                            Where<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderNbr>>,
                            And<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderType>>>>>.Select(Base,
                                                                                                salesOrderNbr,
                                                                                                salesOrderType);

    if (salesOrderEntry != null && salesOrder != null)
    {
        salesOrderEntry.Document.Current = salesOrder;
        throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(salesOrderEntry, "Document") { Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow };
    }

    return adapter.Get();
}
```

If you don't need to select the sales order, this should work too :

```
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "View Sales Order")]
public virtual IEnumerable ViewSalesOrder(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>(), "Document") { Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow };
}
```

For some DAC which have a PXPrimaryGraph attribute you can redirect to the DAC object directly:

```
PXRedirectHelper.TryRedirect(Base, dacObject, PXRedirectHelper.WindowMode.NewWindow);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PXRedirectRequiredException` to open the graph. Even better I like to use `PXRedirectHelper.TryRedirect`. You can search the source to find many examples. Basically you need your graph loaded with your record and the window mode.

Example opening the sales order page...

```
//...
SOOrder doc = PXSelect<SOOrder, Where<SOOrder.noteID, Equal<Required<POFixedDemand.refNoteID>>>>.Select(this, line.RefNoteID);
if (doc != null)
{
    SOOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
    graph.Document.Current = doc;
    PXRedirectHelper.TryRedirect(graph, PXRedirectHelper.WindowMode.NewWindow);
}
//...
```